# Salesforce CPQ, how to move Quote Lines from one Group to another

Tags: cpq

In Salesforce CPQ Quote we had 2 groups, and have few products in each group.
I click on the tab in left margin, to see all groups and then go to each group. Can someone suggest how can i move a product in one group to another group?[image]
see attached screenshot below.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using drag and drop functionality available in Quote Line Editor

As described in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cpq_quote_line_groups.htm&type=5), If you make more groups, you can drag products between different groups.

[image]

To understand how it is done, I recommend watching this Video: [Quote Line Editor QLE Overview | EP3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrY2x13-vlE) (Drag the slider to 18:30)